# stacking 0s and 1s vectors in TensorFlow

Tags: python, concatenation, tensorflow2.0

Suppose `z = 3` and `e = 3`. I need to create a `z x (e*z)` design matrix that looks like this

```
[[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]]
```

How can I get such a matrix in `TensorFlow` using `concat`, `stack`, or `linalg.band_part`? I cannot simply define it by hand, and then convert it into a tensor.

The firs and last `z x e` matrices are easy to achieved by stacking/concatenating vectors of 1s and 0s, but the one in the middle is what I cannot achieve.

UPDATE:
I have used `tf.Variable`, which has an `assign` method

```
e = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((batch_size,z, z*e), dtype=tf.float32))
for b in range(batch_size):
    for i in range(z):
        e = e[b, i, i*e:e*(i+1)].assign(1)
```

While `assign` is very handy for such a purpose, can be problematic in graph mode since `tf.Variable` can only be created once in the computational graph.

Comment: thanks for the correction. Initially, I was trying to write the matrix with markdown but I didnt manege to render the code properly. I need to do it in Tensorflow 2

Comment: Could you add the code you have tried already?